# How to make a button clickable only if the textfield is entered

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, meteor

I had a textfield to enter the emailId..Iam getting that value stored in `$rootScope.emailId`.
Now when I click the submit button,I must take to next page only if the emailId is entered or else it must give an  alert saying that must be filled.
Currently it is in form and i am using `required="true"` and `form.$valid` but still its not working is there any other way to achieve this.

```
<form name="customerForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail" class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1  control-label">Email address</label>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <input class="form-control" ng-model="$root.customerDetails.eMail" placeholder="Enter customer email" type="email" required focus value="{{emailId}}">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

--

```
<div class="col-lg-1">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary right-button" ng-click="$ctrl.proceedToPaymentDetails()" ng-disabled="$ctrl.customerDetails">Next</button>
</div>
```

Currently the form and the button are not in the same html page..Is der any way to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

change  `ng-disabled="customerForm.$invalid"` or you can also check the value of email id inside your proceedToPaymentDetails() method for alert message.

Comment: ng-disabled is not related to this.I removed that...How to check the email id inside the proceedToPaymentDetails()

Answer (score 0):

**Please gone throw this example code for your better understanding**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form novalidate>
    First Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.firstName"><br>
    Last Name:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.lastName">
    <br><br>
        Email:<br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="user.emailID">
    <br><br>
    <button ng-click="proceedToPaymentDetails()">Next</button>
  </form>
  <p>form = {{user}}</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {firstName:"", lastName:"",emailID:""};
    $scope.proceedToPaymentDetails = function() {
        alert($scope.user.emailID);
    };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```